# Autocomplete textview google places api description -> place_id

Tags: java, javascript, android, xml, google-maps

I'm using autocomplete places from Google to get predicions for locations.
Now when they click on one of those predictions I want to get the place_id but I don't know how to do it?

This is my PlcaesAutoCompleteAdapter:

```
public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }

    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "";

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";



    private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;



        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description")+ "," + predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id") );
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

}
```

Now I call it like this in my mainactivity:

```
  autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtEventLocation);
        autoCompView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.places_autocomplete_item));


        //When click on autocomplete suggestion
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                String str = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

When they click on it, I want to get the place_id instead of the description.
So I show the description and they can click on it but I want to get the place_id of it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `resultList` to an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`, so that you can store both the place id and the description.

Change these lines in your code

```
  resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
  for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
       resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description")+ "," + predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id") );
  }
```

to these lines:

```
resultList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(predsJsonArray.lengtgh());
for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length();, i++) {
     HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
     String description = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description");
     String placeId = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id");
     place.put("description", description);
     place.put("place_id", placeId);
     resultList.add(place);
}
```

Also change your `public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>` to `public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>`

In addition, change your

```
@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
     return resultList.get(index);
}
```

to these lines:

```
@Override
Public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int index) {
   return resultList.get(index);
}
```