# Not getting Places data using google Places API - This API project is not authorized to use this API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api, autocompletetextview, google-geocoding-api

I am using the code from the question asked here [Autocomplete textview google places api description -> place_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304352/autocomplete-textview-google-places-api-description-place-id). I changed the code to add it to my app. When I run the code it is giving me the below response when I run the code

```
07-28 11:17:19.244: E/result(350): {"error_message":"This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https:\/\/code.google.com\/apis\/console","predictions":[],"status":"REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

I searched for some threads and from the below threads

1. [Maps API keys for geocoding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061671/maps-api-keys-for-geocoding-not-working)
2. [This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933247/this-ip-site-or-mobile-application-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-key)
   and one or two other

I did the follow steps as suggested.

1. Created a Server Key from console and added it to project.
2. Enabled `Places API` from console.
3. Enabled `Geocoding API` from console.

You can see in below image.
[image]

and when I run the code it still shows me the error mentioned above. **Do I need to Enable any other APIs from console**.

The maps are working good except this. In case you want to know this is my api key added in manifest.

```
<!-- Goolge Maps API Key Development mode -->
            <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAbo3luzbyQTuuPLOyo_Ml***********" />
```

and I am adding server key directly to request url as below

```
private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
ArrayList<String> resultList = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");
        Log.e("result",jsonObj.toString());
        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description")+ "," + predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id") );
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: did you created google places api key?

Comment: i created server key as mentioned, maps are working fine except this.

Comment: please send your manifest.xml

Comment: @KaranMer not server key... you have to create google places api key...

Comment: there is no such thing like google places api key. you can see from docs that you need only server key https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro

Comment: @PierangeloOrizio the project is working fine and I am add server key directly to the request

Comment: @pskink can you have a look at this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Needed some more thorough research and after some trial and error it worked. main thing was that I needed to enable **Google Places API Web Service**. and it worked like charm.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Since you are manually constructing HTTP requests, and sending them to the Web Service endpoint, you need to have the Web Service API enabled. Google also has a native SDK for Android which provides Autocomplete, which is worth looking into: https://developers.google.com/places/android/

Comment: Great.you saved my day buddy. :)

Comment: Nice answer. Working perfect for me also. Only, need to generate server or Browser key for this not android key in that google project after enabling Google Places API Web Service..

Comment: Working perfectly. Just let me know the geocpding api is also needed?

Comment: Answer is correct but seems major glitch in google places api for mobile